# C# Record Screen, Parameter not valid

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, recording

I have recently tried to make a screen recorder, but i'm keep getting this error: *"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"* and the Additional Information: *"Parameter not valid"*. This is the code i have so far:

```
`       
 private Bitmap captureScreen()
 {
     Size s = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
     Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height);
     Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
     g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
     return bm;
 }
 private void screenCapturer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //timer
 {
     screenPreview.Image = captureScreen();
 }
```

`

The error occurs some time after the form has loaded. When i change the interval of the timer the error occurs later.

Thanks.

Comment: which line does it say is throwing that exception?

Comment: This line "Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height);"

Comment: You need to make sure s is not null before checking the width and height.  Not sure if that is your primary issue, but that has the potential to cause problems.

Comment: Are `s.Width` and `s.Height` greater than zero?

Comment: How can i find that out?

Comment: Setting a breakpoint in the debugger or printing the values.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your second line where you create the bitmap.  Run your program and when it breaks hover over your s variable and see if it has any value.  I'm guessing it's null, which will throw an exception when you try to view the values of s.Width and s.Height.

Comment: It says it is 1920x1080.

Comment: So when you set your breakpoint and saw what the values for the width and height were, did it then immediately throw that exception when it tries to run the line creating your bitmap?  Your method gets called for every tick of your timer, so just because you have a width and height now, maybe at some point when it gets called again is when you're running into this issue.